# ASP.NET CORE WEB API System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException on app.UseSession()

Tags: c#, exception, session, asp.net-web-api

I tried to add session for my project. Added Session section in my Program.cs like this :

```
    builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
    builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
    {
       options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    });
```

and

```
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseSession();
```

But when i try call any api even if i don't use session, it throws exception :

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: An error
> occurred while trying to encrypt the provided data. Refer to the inner
> exception for more information. For more information go to
> http://aka.ms/dataprotectionwarning
> ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.UnsafeNativeMethods.CryptProtectData(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*,
> IntPtr, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*, IntPtr, IntPtr,
> UInt32, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB ByRef)'.

Looked for some other questions on stackoverflow but none of them solved it.

Comment: your question doesn't have anything to do with the problem

Comment: i dont know what is the problem relations with, so couldn't write any more info about project. My Project is .net 6 project and has those packages in csproj :

`Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="12.0.1" 
Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.19"
Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core" Version="7.0.8"
Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0"
Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.8"
Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.8"`

Comment: put breakpoint on your program.cs then step over untill you find where the issue originated from

Comment: It opening swagger on start. I mean program runs successfully but when i call api it throws exception. But however doesn't hit api. Probably throws in middleware

Comment: It's something related to `app.UseSession();` section. When i delete it, i can request data from api successfully.

Comment: please provide a screenshot of the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255087/discussion-between-kyree-henry-and-muhammet-kbal).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Kyree Henry, showed me that i was trying add session into web api project.

Since session stores in browser, web api project doesn't support session. Instead of session, memory or redis for cache would fit requirement.